# JS Pan Gestures on Android Webview doesn't work

Tags: javascript, android, webview

pan gesture / scrolling on a web view is not working on a WebView hosting jquery datatables table until a click on a table header is done.

Meaning, the user cannot scroll the table up and down and sideways, until he presses a table header (which sorts the table). This also happens on non-jquery-tables JS code – the WebView is not scrollable. Interesting thing to note, that when I attach a chrome debugger to the WebView, scrolling starts to work.

I’ve tested the same code on Android chrome browser with local and remote JS code – and scrolling works. So this leads me to think that there’s some kind of issue with the WebView itself.
I thought it might be a swipe gesture collision - but there is no swipe gesture defined (meaning the web view is standalone in the activity and there are no windows to swipe to).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should post your code, Android WebView has many options, I'll start testing:

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Also check that javascript is enable.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue.
Probably there's a bug on WebViews on KitKat (and smaller) versions on Android. On Lollipop things work fine.

My workaround for KitKat was to redraw the DOM:

```
 setTimeout(function() { 
     var htmlString = $( '#content' ).html(); 
     $('#content').html(htmlString); 
 }, 1000);
```

That somehow returned "focus" to the DOM and panning gesture works.